# Jquery auto complete feature in combo box with unique values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm using Jquery ui autocomplete plugin in a combo box and I'm reading the values from a JSON file. The problem is in my JSON file. I have fields with same value. Like this.
({
name:a
},
{
name:a
},
{
name:b
})

So when I type 'a' in combo box, it gives me 2 'a' s. But I need only one **(I need only the unique values from JSON file)**. How do I do this? I do not have the complete code right now, that's why I cant put it. Sorry about that and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** You could use something like this to remove duplicate entries from the json array before sending that data to the jQuery autocomplete plugin.

```
var names = {};
var param = "name"
$.each(data.people, function() {
    if (!names[this[param]])
       names[this[param]] = [];   
    names[this[param]].push(this);
});
```

Then we can do `source: names`

Comment: Thank you @farhanahmad So now what I do is, take the JSON file and assign it to jQuery autocomplete plugin from 'source:' element. So its like, 'source:people'. 'people' is my JSON file. What you suggest sir is instead of giving 'people' JSON file directly, filter it for unique values. Ok. I understand that. But after that, how do I set it to 'source' attribute?

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable time. Will try this and let you know. @FarhanAhmad

Answer (score 1):

try this.... only unique values can be added in input field

```
 select: function( event, ui ) {

      var terms = split( this.value );
      // remove the current input
      terms.pop();
      // add the selected item

      if(!($.inArray(ui.item.value,terms) > -1))
      terms.push( ui.item.value );


      // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
      terms.push( "" );
      this.value = terms.join( ", " );
      return false;
    }
```